# Can't change value of a variable in JQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've written a script for a slider. In my code, I define a variable named `autoswitch` having default value `true` and slides will be changed if `autoswitch == true`. But I want If a user clicked on slide's arrow, `autoswitch` changes to `false`. My code is following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Initiate variables
var speed = 500;
var autoswitch = true;
var autoswitch_speed = 5000;

// Add initial active class
$('.slide').first().addClass('active');

// Hide all slides
$('.slide').hide();

$('.slide').first().show();

$('#next').click(function () {
    autoswitch = false;
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
        $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    } else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
});
$('#prev').click(function () {
    autoswitch = false;
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')){
        $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } else{
        $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
});

if(autoswitch){
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else{
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    }, autoswitch_speed);
}
});
```

I have two slider arrow and both of them on click, in the first line of function change the value of `autoswitch = false;`, but this trick doesn't work and even after clicking on arrows, slides switch automatically! How can I solve my problem?

Comment: uhm. that if statement only happens once. Once it runs it's done and the interval has begun or never will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is happening because you have already created the `setInterval` object on page load. You need to delete the `timer object` on `autoswitch = false`

You need to update your code to

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
        $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    } else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
}, autoswitch_speed);
```

Call it on `autoswitch = false`

```
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have started the setInterval so to stop that you need to call clearInterval on arrow click

Try below code it should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initiate variables
    var speed = 500;
    var autoswitch = true;
    var autoswitch_speed = 5000;

    // Add initial active class
    $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

    // Hide all slides
    $('.slide').hide();

    $('.slide').first().show();

    $('#next').click(function () {
        clearInterval(cleanVar);
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        } else{
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    });
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        clearInterval(cleanVar);
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')){
            $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
        } else{
            $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
        $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
    });



      var cleanVar =  setInterval(autoScroll, autoswitch_speed);

    });

    function autoScroll() {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
            if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
                $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
            } else{
                $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
            }
            $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
            $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
            $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
        }
```